# The system cannot find the file specified when calling copy from python

Tags: python, windows

Here's my copy.py:

```
from subprocess import call
call("copy p2.txt p3.txt")
```

If in command prompt I use

`copy p2.txt p3.txt` it copies fine.

but when I use `python copy.py` it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copy.py", line 2, in <module>
    call("copy p2.txt p3.txt")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

If I replace the python call to copy with xcopy, it works fine.

Why would this be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `subprocess.call()`ing a command like in a shell, you'll need to specify [`shell=True`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) as well.

```
from subprocess import call
call("copy p2.txt p3.txt", shell=True)
```

The reason you need to use `shell=True` in this case is that the `copy` command in Windows is not actually an executable but a built-in command of the shell (if memory serves right). `xcopy` on the other hand is a real executable (in `%WINDIR%\System32`, which is usually in the `%PATH%`), so it can be called outside of a `cmd.exe` shell.

In this particular instance, [`shutil.copy` or `shutil.copy2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) might be viable alternatives.

Please note that using `shell=True` can lead to security hazards, or as the docs put it:

> Warning: Using `shell=True` can be a security hazard. See the warning under [Frequently Used Arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) for details.

Comment: Updated my answer explaining why `copy` fails without `shell=True`.